# Data ListView in Fragment not showing

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I followed similar questions on site and none have resolved my issue.I am just getting a single line where my listview is supposed to be in the fragment.I have already made the adapter in the Activity before I add the fragment. Please help.

```
public class Frag1 extends Fragment
{
    ListView listView;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
         View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
         listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_view);
         return view;


    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);




        listView.setAdapter(FragActivity.adapter);
    }
}
```

onCreate() method of Activity

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fragment);
        adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, R.layout.List_viewit, arr);
        if (savedInstanceState == null)
        {

            getFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new Frag1())
                    .commit();
        }
  }
```

adapter is of the class CustomAdapter extending ArrayAdapter.The listview was showing data when in activity but not when I am trying to implement it in fragment.The array arr is non-zero.

Comment: you should be extending the frag1 class with ListFragment, check this tutorial http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_list_fragment.htm

Comment: I understood that you have declared adapter in activity class then use this adapter in fragment. am i right?

Comment: @Masum Yes I initialized the adapter in the activity before adding the fragment.

Comment: Can you post your activity class code where you declare adapter.

Comment: Please post your adapter and Activity class

Comment: Do you override onActivityCreated() method in fragment parent activity?

Comment: How do you access your adapter object as I can see in your code "adapter" is not mentioned any where in your fragment.

Comment: Check this [link](http://androhub.com/newversion/2015/09/17/android-material-design-tabs-using-tablayout/).

Comment: Please check the edits regarding the adapter object.

Answer (score 0):

Can you do this.

Your FragmentActivity

```
BaseAdapter mAdapter;
public BaseAdapter getmAdapter() {
    return mAdapter;
}
```

Your Fragment Class

```
YourFragmentActivity mActivity;
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        mActivity = ((YourFragmentActivity) activity);
    } catch (ClassCastException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    listView.setAdapter(mActivity.getmAdapter());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

don't call `listView.setAdapter(FragActivity.adapter);`
in `OnActivityCreate()` method. call in `onCreatview` or in whenever fragment is visible to the use.

Answer (score 0):

Declare your adapter in your FragActivity class  as static. Something like this

```
public static CustomAdapter adapter;
```